# jest error: const warnedKeys: {[string]: boolean} = {};

Tags: react-native, testing, jestjs, react-native-testing-library

If I run `yarn test`, which runs `jest`, I get the following error:

```
C:\react-native-project\node_modules\react-native\Libraries\Utilities\warnOnce.js:15
    const warnedKeys: {[string]: boolean} = {};
```

But that only happens if I follow the [directions](https://github.com/callstack/react-native-testing-library) of the `react-native-testing-library`:

> Then automatically to add it to your jest tests by using setupFilesAfterEnv option in the
>   jest.config.js file:

If I remove the file I will not get *that* error and I can get simple tests to run. When I remove the file, the test runs but `AsyncStorage` is not recognized so the tests still don't run. I have `AsyncStorage`. It's installed and the app works, but I want to add component tests. I also noticed the file, `jest.config.js`, is conspicuously missing from the testing project itself. Is there any documentation or working example? I would rather not do a diff of my project and the testing project. Is there a more well-documented or reliable testing framework/module available?

Answer (score 0):

I'm able to get working tests by following the [documentation](https://www.native-testing-library.com/) of the React Native Testing Library with the npm package name of `@testing-library/react-native` not to be confused with the React Native Testing Library with the npm package name of `react-native-testing-library`. Both packages allow testing components and are recommended by React-Native [documentation](https://reactnative.dev/docs/testing-overview#component-tests) but this one works when following the instructions. It also has [instructions](https://www.native-testing-library.com/docs/setup) "to define a custom render method that includes things like global context providers, data stores, etc" so that testing components with `AsyncStorage` and such shouldn't be a problem.